# Automatically Insert Into Post when uploading Media

Tags: multisite, uploads, media

When files are uploaded, I would like the, to automatically get inserted, bypassing the need to click on the "Insert into post" button

I use WordPress Multisite 3.5

[image]

I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
add_filter( 'flash_uploader', '_force_html_uploader' );

function _force_html_uploader( $flash ) {
    remove_action('post-html-upload-ui', 'media_upload_html_bypass' );
    return false;
}

add_action('media_upload_tabs', '_media_upload_auto_insert_js');

function _media_upload_auto_insert_js(){
    ?><script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/upload.js"></script><?php
}
```

// uploads.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if(jQuery(".savesend input")){
        jQuery(".savesend input").click();
    }
});
```

I also tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
function wpse167143_admin_footer() {
?>
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    typeof wp.Uploader !== 'undefined' && wp.Uploader.queue.on( 'reset', function () {
        // From the primary toolbar (".media-toolbar-primary")
        // get the insert button view (".media-button-insert")
        // and execute its click (as specified in its options).
        wp.media.frame.toolbar.get('primary').get('insert').options.click();
    } );
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer' , 'wpse167143_admin_footer' );
```

thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

That's the pre-3.5 media interface so I think you must be on 3.4.x? Anyway the first way should work as long as you're using the browser (non-multifile) upload... try changing

```
add_filter( 'flash_uploader', '_force_html_uploader' );
```

to

```
add_action( 'pre-html-upload-ui', '_force_html_uploader' );
```

and the "js/upload.js" (note the subdirectory - it's expected to be in a "js" subdirectory of your theme directory) to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if (typeof 'switchUploader' === 'function') switchUploader(1);
    if(jQuery(".savesend input")){
        jQuery(".savesend input").click();
    }
});
```

Neither change is that important, they just ensure your using the browser upload - which is important. The (other) important thing is that "js/upload.js" gets loaded (you can check it's being loaded by inspecting the frame source).